# PyCharm showing "Download grammar and spelling checker for Asturian"

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

PyCharm has recently started showing me a suggestion to download spell checker for Asturian. What is this **Asturian**? I couldn't find anything useful with a simple Google search.

PS: I use PyCharm to write deep learning code in Python.

Comment: *"What is this Asturian? I couldn't find anything useful with a simple Google search."* -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asturian_language

Comment: Looks like the IDE treated some of your comments/strings as words in that language (why? no ideas, could be because of some typos there etc) and offered to download and install a dictionary for such a language. You may just click "Do not offer" (or is it "Ignore"?) so it will not appear again (at very least for this project).

Answer (score 3):

There is an [asturian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asturian_language) and PyCharm recommends to download grammar and spell checker for this language

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).